# using NgRx Effect

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

We are developing an app using Angular 8 and NgRx for state management. In the app we have about 10 components, every one of them uses a unique `API` 
all the `API` need same data from the user `(id) -- { the user enter the (id) in input field }`

The question: Should I use the effects to call all the `API` when the user enter the (`id`) and store the data in the STORE or just store the `id` in state then every component call its own `API` when `id` change?

Note: The data coming from the `API` is used in its own component only.

Comment: if you still use the store, then use effects because if you do not use effects every time you go to the respective component you will make requests for api

Answer (score 1):

To use an effect to call an API - that's the right way. Simply dispatch its action.

To store response data in store - depends.
If you want to use it later somewhere in your app - then store it, if you don't need it - then add `{ dispatch: false }` to the `createEffect` options to avoid post process of it.

Comment: The main problem that i dont want to store the data of all of the 10 API  in the store -- the data of every Api used in its own component only--- so can i pass the data from the effect to the component directly or something like that

Comment: Aha, that's against flux approach. Its goal that data and its presentation are separated and it doesn't matter where the data is used, in 1 or in 10 components. If you need it - it should be in the store.
If you need this data only for a single component - then you need to have an action to remove the data from store and dispatch it in ngOnDestroy, so when a user is leaving a component the data is removed from store.

Comment: Last question.. if i keep the data of this 10 api and all the Api in the app inside the store ..does theis affect in any way in the app performance ....or i just simply call the api in its own component without using effect

Comment: And use the effect just for the api that i need to use in multiple components

Comment: if you keep the data of all 10 API - it only consumes memory and performance can be degraded if browser consumes too much memory. If data isn't huge - it shouldn't affect much. if you use createSelector or createFeatureSelector functions from ngrx - they have internal memory that gives max performance regardless amount of data in the store.

Comment: My advice would be - if you know that the data from the API will not ever used in a different component - simply use a service for this component to avoid ngrx complexity. If there's a chance that it will be used somewhere else - then it's worth investing some time to implement ngrx store for it.